# Can Ubuntu create file system over 200TB?

Tags: xfs

Need to implement Veeam Linux Harden Repo over 200TB capacity can Ubuntu create XFS over 200TB?

Answer (score 3):

The [XFS filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) supports up to 8 exibytes volumes.

ZFS supports even larger volume sizes, since it's a 128-bit filesystem.

Comment: Thx a lot for info